# Bubble sort in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

How can I make this better?

```
public int BubbleSortNonEfficient(int[] arr) {
            int temp = 0;
            int LoopCount = 0;
            for(int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++) {
                for(int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++) {
                    LoopCount++;
                    if(arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1]) {
                        temp = arr[sort + 1];
                        arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                        arr[sort] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return LoopCount;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation will run in quadratic time in all cases. You can optimize here a bit:

```
public static int BubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    int loopCount = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; ++i) {
        bool swapped = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - i; ++j) {
            loopCount++;

            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                swapped = true;
                int temp = arr [j];
                arr [j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr [j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }

        if (!swapped) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return loopCount;
}
```

The above alternative will run faster whenever the input array is "presorted," i.e., exhibits a lot of order.

Declaring the sort as `static` will allow the user to use your sort without actually instantiating the class it belongs to.

Last but not least: you can declare **`temp`** in the body of the inner loop, since it affects nothing.

Comment: thanks but I want to count so I can see wich ones are better

Comment: @Moder Answer edited.